# Prove ¬∃x ∀y (E(x, y) ↔ ¬E(y, y)) given no premises

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

[image]

The only way I could think of to do this problem is reductio, but since the two biconditional terms are not contradictory, I am pretty stuck.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the law of excluded middle?

Comment: I think you perform existential and universal elimination on your reductio premise and reach a contradiction

Answer (score 2):

Smells like Russell's Paradox ...

Anyway, yes, you totally had the right idea: proof by contradiction!  And the two conditionals will contradict as long as you instantiate them with the same constant a:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

E(x,y) <-> ¬ E(y,y) is clearly false if x and y are the same, because then the statement becomes E(x,x) <-> ¬ E(x,x).

Whatever we choose for x, E(x,y) <-> ¬ E(y,y) is not true for all y, because it is not true for y = x.

Comment: This is only correct in classical logics; see the discussion under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using the law of excluded middle. After eliminating the existential quantifier to get *x*, apply the universal quantification on *x* itself to get E(x,x) ↔ ¬E(x,x). This is false if E(x,x) is true or false.

[image]

In Coq:

```
Variable P : Prop -> Prop -> Prop.
Axiom LEM : forall p, p \/ ~p.

Goal ~exists x, forall y, (P x y -> ~P y y) /\ (~P y y -> P x y).
intro.
elim H.
intros.
assert (P x x \/ ~P x x) by apply LEM.
elim H1; intro.
apply H0 with x; assumption.
apply H0 with x; apply H0; assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: It is unclear whether "no premises" means no law of excluded middle. If yes, I'll remove this.

Comment: Since you can prove LEM from no premises, you could always begin with that proof and satisfy the terms of the question.

Comment: @Dennis LEM does not hold in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: I was assuming OP was working in a classical system. Since most intro logic books assume such a system it seems likely, but you’re right that it wouldn’t be an intuitionistically valid proof.